# Changing path of Xcode Server

Tags: xcode, server.app, webserver

I'm running Xcode Server on my Mac Mini, and the HTTP port is open to the internet. I want to be able to host other content on port 80.

Is there a way I can change the path where the Xcode Server webpage is hosted?

To clarify, I want to access Xcode Server by typing either `http://host.name.tld/xcode` or `http://host.name.tld:43211`, rather than it being the root document served on port 80. I can't find anything to this effect in the auto-configured Apache config file.

Comment: For clarification: What exactly do you want to change: The Port (80) or the path (where the files are) ?

Comment: Well, either, actually. But I'd like to access http://host.name.tld/xcode instead of it being the root.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with the OS X Server app.

1. Open Server.app.
2. Go to the Websites service.

   [image]
3. Double-click your server website in the list.

   [image]
4. Click Edit… for Index Files.

   [image]
5. Delete /xcode/ from the list.

   [image]
6. Click OK on both boxes and wait for the service to update.

   [image]
   [image]

Then Xcode will only be accessible from host.name.tld/xcode

Comment: Didn't work for me, unfortunately.

Answer (score 5):

First, make sure you are looking at the right apache config.  Base OS X includes a config file, but the one used in Server is at `/Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2/sites`.

The two lines that makes Xcode the default is in `0000_any_80_.conf`:

```
DocumentRoot "/Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/Default"
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php /xcode/ /wiki/ default.html
```

That means Apache will look for an index first in `/Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/Default`, but if there isn't an index file, it will try to use /xcode/ as the index (and will fall back to the wiki after that).

To override it, all you need to do is put some content in index.html. After that, you will still be able to access Xcode server in http://host.name.tld/xcode

Answer (score 0):

In an effort to keep this somewhat up to date, deleting Xcode's config file  as suggested by [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205290) seems to do the trick:
`/Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2/other/COM.APPLE.WEBAPP.XCODE.conf`

The server root no longer **always** redirects to `http://example.com/xcode/`, and Xcode is still accessible via `http://example.com/xcode/`.

Now, if someone knows how to make it *only* accessible via a specific subdomain (`http://xcode.example.com/xcode/`), I'm all ears...